# Fullcalendar: How to display round clock only on axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

So when I set options for Full calendar I have the following code

```
    var defaults = {
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    header: {
        left: '',
        center: 'title',
        right: ''
    },
    slotDuration: '00:20:00',
    weekends: false,
    editable: true,
    allDaySlot: false,
    eventDurationEditable: false,
    height: "auto",
    minTime: "08:00:00",
    maxTime: "24:00:00",
    axisFormat: 'h(:mm)a'
};
```

And it gives me something like this

[image]

However, I do not want those 8:20am,8:40am tickers. What could I do to remove those?

Comment: Do you want 1 hour slot duration i.e. 8am,9am... Make slotDuration: '01:00:00'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can not do it setting properties of the calendar. But reviewing the source code you can see,  inside function in charge of draw the html for every slot at [line 5798 of version 2.1.1](https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/blob/master/dist/fullcalendar.js#L5798):

```
((!slotNormal || !minutes) ? // if irregular slot duration, or on the hour, then display the time
```

So, if you change that line to display only when the minutes are 0 (o'clock!)

```
((!minutes) ?
```

Then you are done.